# My HTML Emails are not getting formatted as HTML?

Tags: php, html, email, header

Not sure what is wrong, I made sure to set my headers so perhaps something is wrong. The mailscript that I have is huge so I put together this little tester, when i receive the emails all the html tags are present but no formatting took place. I'm curious if it's a problem with the way I set up the header or if I needed more to it. I searched the forums and it looked like the problem most people had was they weren't adding in the HTML content-type but that is added in here, so any help would be awesome.

thanks

Okay so I've checked out some tutorials online
http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=416467
http://css-tricks.com/2866-sending-nice-html-email-with-php
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['new_count'])) //counts how many fake emails i send myself
{
    $count = $_SESSION['new_count'];
}
else
{
    //first time
    $count = 0;
}

$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'email test';
$message = '<html><head></head><body>';
$message .= '<h1>this is an email test</h1>';
$message .= '<br />does new line work?<br />';
$message .= 'how about <b>bold</b> and <strong>strong</strong>?<br />';
$message .= '</body></html>';
//updated my header to include mime-version
$mailheader = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n';
$mailheader .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . '\r\n';
$mailheader .= 'from: abc@def.com <btyazaki@gmail.com>' . '\r\n';

$yay = mail($to,$subject,$message,$mailheader);

if($yay)
{
    echo 'woot';
    $count++;
    $_SESSION['new_count'] = $count;
    echo '<br>Emails Sent: '.$count;
}
else
{
    echo 'no woot';
}
?>
```

I updated the headers to the suggested forms on W3 and a few other places. I'm guessing that my headers are the problem... this still outputs regular text not html not sure what the problem is. As for the structure of this script it's not my actual mailer script it's a test script w/ a counter so I know how many emails to look out for during a test session.

Comment: This is not the way to send a HTML E-Mail. Refer to Stack Overflow's or Google's search to find out how it's done

Comment: Pekka, thanks for the info. I did do a google search and I looked into some of the Stack Overflow's suggested topics prior to asking my question. Most of what I found was that it was problems declaring the header, but my header looks like it should according to the tutorials I posted up, curious as to what is screwing up the email.

Comment: You're not using `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags for starters. Email clients are picky.

Comment: oh my bad, my updated script does have the <html> <head> and <body> tags...

Comment: If you want to use escape characters such as `\r\n` then you must use double-quoted strings in PHP.

Comment: FWIW, I've *never* needed `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags, and from what I've read: most mail clients discard them. But yeah, email can be tricky business - best to look into a pre-built library like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or something.

Comment: [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org)  will do all that for your with far less hassle and much less code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using double quotes for your \r\n.

```
$mailheader = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= 'from: abc@def.com <btyazaki@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: +1 This is more than likely the solution since everything else seems to be in order.

Comment: this was the solution, I didn't realize I had to double quote the the return and newline characters. Thanks so much. Would that be the reason that my newline characters aren't working when I try to send a normal text email?

Comment: Yes, any escape characters should be wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use [Swift](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html), which makes it very easy to send email in PHP. An even better solution would be to use something like [Postmarkapp](http://postmarkapp.com/), which an addition of having excellent libraries, also makes sure your messages doesn't get stuck in spam filters etc.

Example with Swift:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

//Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

  //Give the message a subject
  ->setSubject('Your subject')

  //Set the From address with an associative array
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))

  //Set the To addresses with an associative array
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))

  //Give it a body
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')

  //And optionally an alternative body
  ->addPart('<q>Here is the message itself</q>', 'text/html')

  //Optionally add any attachments
  ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('my-document.pdf'))
  ;
```

Comment: I appreciate it, I'm probably going to integrate using a mailer app/library on my personal site, but I didn't want to have a bunch of extra stuff doing this clients site, he gets really touchy about using outside script whether free or not, not sure why.

Comment: @Brodie: Sorry to hear that, [here's something to cheer you up](http://clientsfromhell.net/) :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the "From" should be before the "Content-type". On top of this you should not need the "MIME" header.